# Robot Framework keywords and Inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, robotframework

I have a library of keywords.  I have a few classes and subclasses, but I'm having an issue with inheritance and keywords being double-defined.  For example:

MyLib.py

```
class Class1:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def do_something_generic(self):
    #do stuff that is generic to all subclasses
    pass

class Subclass1(Class1):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def do_something_specific_to_subclass1(self):
    #something specific
    pass

class Subclass2(Class1):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def do_something_specific_to_subclass2(self):
    #something specific
    pass
```

The specific keywords work fine, but when I try to call `Do Something Generic` I get `Multiple keywords with name 'Do Something Generic' found`.  I can fully qualify the library name with `MyLib.Class1.Do Something Generic`, but is there any way to define `Do Something Generic` to always refer to the superclass, since the method is only defined there and is simply inherited by the subclasses?

Answer (score 0):

From [Robot Framework User Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#what-methods-are-considered-keywords)

```
When the static library API is used, Robot Framework uses reflection to find out what public methods the library class or module implements.
It will exclude all methods starting with an underscore,
and with Java libraries also methods that are implemented only in java.lang.Object are ignored.
All the methods that are not ignored are considered keywords.
```

Have you considered adding helper base class with a `_do_something_generic` function? You can exclude it from `__all__` list. Then use the inheritance to expose keywords from the base class in `Class1`.

```
MyLibrary.py:
__all__ = ['Class1', 'Subclass1', 'Subclass2']

class BaseClass:
  def _do_something_generic(self):
    pass

class Class1(BaseClass):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def do_something_generic(self):
    return self._do_something_generic()

class Subclass1(BaseClass):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def do_something_specific_to_subclass1(self):
    a = self._do_something_generic()
    return (a, 3)

class Subclass2(BaseClass):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def do_something_specific_to_subclass2(self):
    #something specific
    pass
```

Comment: the issue is there are operations that are generic to Class1 but do things involving the subclasses.  for example, in my case the Class1 refers to an ssh connection library, while the subclasses refer to specific things I may do over that ssh connection, like using a particular CLI.  so I would want a `Disconnect` keyword that kills the ssh connection, but I want it generic to the ssh library.

Comment: i suppose the issue could be that Robot isnt really Object Oriented, so the link between the non-OO robot framework and the OO python code its built on is a bit confusing

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to simply move `do_something_generic` to a separate class, so that your base class only has helper functions and no public keywords:

```
class Class1:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

class Subclass0(Class1):
  def do_something_generic(self):
    #do stuff that is generic to all subclasses
    pass
```

While it might be possible to solve this with something exotic like using `__slots__` or `__getattr__`, or modifying `self.__dict__`, it's probably not worth the trouble.